# Issue with Custom Credential Provider Terminating After UpdateRemoteCredential and SetSerialization Calls

Tags: c#, windows, rdp, credential-providers, winlogon

I’m currently developing a custom credential provider and have encountered a perplexing issue.

Specifically, I’m having trouble with the `UpdateRemoteCredential` and `SetSerialization` methods. After these methods are called, my credential provider unexpectedly terminates. This results in the logon screen being displayed without using the previous serializations. Moreover, even static members are re-initialized after this termination, which means that I can’t store the serializations I have got in the `SetSerialization` method.

Interestingly, the Windows logon process successfully calls `SetUserArray` after calling `SetSerialization`. However, no method in that process is called afterwards and another process begins with re-initializing static members and re-initializing a credential provider and a credential provider credential.

If `UpdateRemoteCredentials` wouldn’t change the credentials and credentials would be passed to the default windows password provider, the logon process would be done perfectly. But if I redirect the serialization to my credential provider and store it in my program, after calling `SetUserArray` my program terminates.

This problem persists even if I don’t do any logic in `SetSerialization`.

I’m seeking a working example of a simple implementation of these two methods that will result in redirecting the incoming serialization to our `SetSerialization` method and storing the serialization to use it in our `GetSerialization` method. For simplicity, let’s assume that the input credentials (receiving remote credentials) are obtained from the default Windows password provider.

Additionally, I’m curious about whether these two methods (`UpdateRemoteCredentials` and `SetSerialization`) need to be implemented in two different classes or if it’s acceptable to implement both `ICredentialProvider` and `ICredentialProviderFilter` in one class.

Currently, I’m working in C#, using `CredProvider.NET.Interop2`. However, I’m open to implementing them in C++, if that would be more effective. If so, could you provide guidance on how to call them from a C# implementation (wrapping them)?

Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated!

### Edit 1:

I have some additional information that might be helpful. Here is a part of the log related to the issue:

```
{ "processId": "8576", "level": "TRACE", "method": "CredentialProvider.UpdateRemoteCredential"}
{ "processId": "8576", "level": "TRACE", "method": "CredentialProvider.Filter"}
{ "processId": "8576", "level": "TRACE", "method": "CredentialProvider.SetUsageScenario"}
{ "processId": "8576", "level": "TRACE", "method": "CredentialProvider.SetSerialization"}
{ "processId": "8576", "level": "TRACE", "method": "CredentialProvider.SetUserArray"}
{ "processId": "6492", "level": "TRACE", "method": "CredentialProvider.SetUsageScenario"}
```

From the log, it’s evident that after the `SetUserArray` method is called, another process is initialized and the constructor of our Credential Provider is invoked on it. I’ve also noticed that the process where `UpdateRemoteCredential` is called never appears in the logger after the completion of `SetUserArray`.

I’ve confirmed that the serialization is correctly passed to `SetSerialization` (with interception by `UpdateRemoteCredentials` and changing CLSID). Unfortunately, I can’t provide the log of this verification due to security reasons. However, I can confirm that the content of the buffer in `SetSerialization` is identical to the input of `UpdateRemoteCredentials`.

Regardless of the specific error, I am seeking a working example of the implementation of `UpdateRemoteCredentials` and `SetSerialization` in C#. My goal is to redirect the incoming serialization (packed by the PasswordProvider) to our credential provider, and then store this serialization in our program for use in `GetSerialization`.

In my current implementation, the serialization is stored, but the `GetSerialization` method is not called on that process. Furthermore, we don’t have access to our stored serialization in `GetSerialization`. Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated.

I hope this additional information and request can provide more context to my issue.

Comment: *my credential provider unexpectedly terminates.* probably logonui crashed. provider can not "terminated" only process. many words, no any useful details

Comment: @RbMm Thank you for your feedback. I agree with you that the issue seems to be related to a LogonUI crash. I’ve tried kernel debugging and even disassembling the LogonUI, but I haven’t been able to pinpoint the problem. Could you please specify what additional details would be helpful for you to better understand my issue?

Comment: not need kernel debugger. user mode live debugger is ok here. create detail log file. log and process id at begin. every method which is called on your interfaces. you not show any code. not debug and not show where crash. *disassembling the LogonUI* - absolute senseless

Comment: *two methods (UpdateRemoteCredentials and SetSerialization) need to be implemented in two different classes* - of course yes. it will be called on different in memory objects. this objects need to implememt different interfaceses.

Comment: @RbMm I understand that these methods need to be implemented for different interfaces. My question was whether it’s possible to implement these two interfaces in a single class. As you can see from the logs I provided, UpdateRemoteCredentials and SetSerialization are called on the same process. Is it necessary to implement these two interfaces separately, provide two different GUIDs for them, and register them separately with COM?

Comment: this is senseless. assume you implement it in common class which implement both interfaces - what is this give you ?

Comment: and this logs, with such details, almost nothing give. need detail logs or debug

Comment: Credential Provider Filter is a dark matter - use it with care. It may bring a lot of underwater rocks into your project. I suggest you to not implement the ICredentialProviderFilter interface on this stage.